# Subtyping arguments of functions with flowtype

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I have few several types in my apps which has few attributes in common. I abstracted common attributes into separated type. Now I would like to write a function that accept any type which has the base type in common.

This few lines explains the problem much better then the words:

```
type Box = {
  width: number,
  height: number,
}

// is like Box + it has position
type PositionedBox = Box & {
  type: 'positionedBox',
  left: number,
  top: number,
}

// is like Box + it has colo
type ColorBox = Box & {
  type: 'colorBox',
  color: string,
}

const logSize = (obj: Box) => {
  console.log({ w: obj.width, h: obj.height });
};

const logPosition = (obj: PositionedBox) => {
  console.log({ l: obj.left, t: obj.top });
};

const logColor = (obj: ColorBox) => {
  console.log({color: obj.color});
};

// this function should accept any Box like type
const logBox = (obj: Box) => {
  logBox(obj);
  // $ERROR - obj Box has no type property
  // (make sense at some point, but how to avoid it?)
  if (obj.type === 'colorBox') logColor(obj);
  if (obj.type === 'positionedBox') logPosition(obj);
}
```

**The question is:** How the `logBox()` function declaration should looks like in order to pass flowtype check.

Comment: can't you just test the existence of `type` property before comparing the value? Or maybe just add a simple `'Box'` type property to the generic type?

Comment: @Kaddath Checking existence of `type` prop doesn't change much I will still get "property not found in object type".

I was playing with generic types, but I couldn't make it working. How would do this?

Comment: to add a type `Box` to the generic one doesn't solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors are legitimate since there is nothing stopping me from passing `{width: 5, height: 5, type: 'colorBox'}` to the `logBox` function, since that is a subtype of `Box`. If you really want to accept any subtype of `Box` you will have to deal with the consequences, which are that checking the `type` field gives you no information about any other properties.

If you want to only allow specific subtypes of `Box`, then you want a [disjoint union](http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions.html). Below I have renamed `Box` to `BaseBox` and added a separate `Box` type that is a union of the two specialized boxes. This example passes.

```
type BaseBox = {
  width: number,
  height: number,
}

// is like Box + it has position
type PositionedBox = BaseBox & {
  type: 'positionedBox',
  left: number,
  top: number,
}

// is like Box + it has colo
type ColorBox = BaseBox & {
  type: 'colorBox',
  color: string,
}

type Box = PositionedBox | ColorBox;

const logSize = (obj: Box) => {
  console.log({ w: obj.width, h: obj.height });
};

const logPosition = (obj: PositionedBox) => {
  console.log({ l: obj.left, t: obj.top });
};

const logColor = (obj: ColorBox) => {
  console.log({color: obj.color});
};

// this function should accept any Box like type
const logBox = (obj: Box) => {
  logBox(obj);
  // $ERROR - obj Box has no type property
  // (make sense at some point, but how to avoid it?)
  if (obj.type === 'colorBox') logColor(obj);
  if (obj.type === 'positionedBox') logPosition(obj);
}
```